# python subprocess.popen get into an infinite loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to run the folowing command on a sub process and collecting the output.

```
nmap -n -PN -sT -T4  -p 445,139 10.11.1.0/24 --exclude matrix
```

this command return an error which is fine by me.

The problem is when i'm doing this from python like this:

```
import subprocess
nmap_process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)        
output,errOutput=nmap_process.communicate()
```

the process hang.
if i don't use the stderr param,the first error line of namp is printed in an infinite loop

does anybody have any segesstion about how to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import subprocess
cmd = "nmap -n -PN -sT -T4  -p 445,139 10.11.1.0/24 --exclude matrix"
pro = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
pro.communicate() #[0] is stdout [1] is stderr :P
```

self.nmap_process.communicate() seems to be your problem. Are you creating this inside a class? Can we see more of the code? Also when I run a nmap stderr cmd in the same code I don't get a hang in my code, and It doesn't infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks mate but the problem remains, this was a typo in my post above i use the same code you wrote and get the problem.

Comment: @jojo: The answer given was based on your previous edit. Just because you made a mistake, doesn't mean that you downvote the answer.

Comment: @@AA:I do appreciate the effort @Jakob Bowyer done , however even with my typo that wasn’t the answer. I would vote him up but this will confuse other people that may think this was the answer.if you run @Jakob Bowyer code you will set that the process hang

Comment: If you add more of your code to the question I might give a better answer :P

Comment: thanks @Jakob Bowyer , I run the code outside eclipse an it works fine, I run from eclipse and i get the above problem,so Thanks for the help i have marked your answer as the answer, if you will edit your answer i can vote it up

Comment: Edit it how? I don't understand that.

Comment: add space or what ever, forum policy doesn't let me voting this up if i have already voted it done unless it is modified